# Insert Page break in examdesign class

Tags: page-breaking, examdesign

I'm working with the `examdesign` class to create a test. I would like to insert page breaks after certain sections (but not all). I have tried each of the following code snippets.

```
\documentclass{examdesign}
\class{test}
\begin{document}
  \begin{matching}
    \pair{A}{B}
    \pair{C}{D}
    %etc, etc
  \end{matching}
  \pagebreak
  \begin{matching}[title={sure}]
    %more pairs here
  \end{matching}
  \pagebreak
\end{document}
```

Instead of `\pagebreak`, I've also tried:

```
\newpage

\clearpage

\exam{\pagebreak}

\exam{\newpage}

\exam{\clearpage}
```

All of those were put in the same place in the code that the \pagebreak was put. None of these is inserting page breaks. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Just realized after I posted this and shut down my computer for the evening that the position of these might matter. I've edited to provide the context

Comment: Can you make your example compilable, please?

Comment: Done, could you take a look at it now?

Comment: It's still not compilable. If I add a `\class`, your minimal example works fine (the `\pagebreak` happens). So please make sure your example reproduces your issue as well.

Comment: Just tried to compile you snippet ... doesn't work.

Comment: It was missing the \class variable because I typed it up at midnight last night my time. I tried it again in my original document and I eventually got it to work, but only if I put a blank line after \pagebreak. Is that required? In any case, I got it working though I don't understand why.

Comment: @Jonathanb No, at least not in the example code in your question. As it stands now, your question is not clear -- can you clarify further with a reproducible example, or can we close this question if is it a non-issue now?

Comment: I guess we should close it. I'm hesitant to post the actual test questions on here, but I haven't been able to get a MWE that actually causes the problem. Furthermore, I have it working in my actual test so maybe I was just misspelling \pagebreak 8 times in a row? At any rate, please close the question. Sorry for the inconvenience.